# Installing eclipse brings me to error website

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

While trying to install `eclipse neon`. I click on the downloaded file and [this webpage pops up:](http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_7_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png)

However, I checked and I have JRE 1.8 so why can't I install it ?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25
```

Comment: JDK != JRE, go get a compiler from oracle and I expect it'll stop complaining.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the latest 1.8? It can make a difference.

Answer (score -2):

You need the Java Development Kit (JDK), these contains the libraries used for development

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html